# plpythonu: Read

Tags: postgresql, plpython

The application "foo" uses this plpythonu source code to read the custom variable `foo.transaction_id`.

I guess this is way too complicated.

How to shorten/simplify below lines?

```
txid_list = list(plpy.execute(
    '''SELECT current_setting FROM current_setting('foo.transaction_id')'''))
txid_str = txid_list [0]['current_setting']
txid = int(txid_str)
```

Comment: `select current_setting('foo.transaction_id')` would just be the same, but I doubt there is a big difference in performance. Not sure if it's possible in Python do do something like `txid := current_setting('foo.transaction_id')` (as in PL/pgSQL)

Comment: I think this is the idiomatic way if you really have to use PL/Python.

Comment: @dezso above code is just one snippet of a bigger PL/Python method. I just thought to myself that this looks simplifiable.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-database.html), you won't be able to simplify this.  `plpy` offers a quite limited set of DB access functions, so you have to do everything using those - basically the way you do it already.